# Publishing Project without Visual Studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, publishing

**Question 1:**

> We need to know whether there is a way of publishing project via
>   clickonce without Visual Studio or rather without buying another
>   licence of Visual Studio?

Why I'm asking this is, our IT audit requirement is pushing someone else; designated except for the Developer to publish the project.

Currently we have a single licensed Visual Studio 2012 Professional version for developer only. Is there anyway for a person who is not much tech savvy to publish without using Visual Studio?

We found that tool such Mage and MageUI are there, but requires far bit of a knowledge to do so.

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: This question should be split into two questions. Please edit/update your question.

Comment: 1. Use VS Express, which is free.

Comment: 2. ClickOnce is the only deployment technology built into VS Express.

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono will do so.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks a lot! Glad that VS Express has it. Will do some round of testing!